# ArXiv/Problems with downloading source

Tags: pdftex, text

Please, how do I download **pure text source file** from [here](https://arxiv.org/format/0903.3428)? I'm running Windows 8 and do not have commant line with gunzip command. The connection with LaTeX and this site is that I want to open it in WinEdt 9, the latex editor.

**EDIT** I have now 2 files E53.tex and E53.bbl. HOWEVER this error occurs WHAT'S WRONG?:

Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\E53.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/TH0dipl/E53.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\amstex\base\amstex.tex

AmS-TeX- Version 2.2

Loading definitions for misc utility macros, page layout, accents/punctuation,
line and page breaks, figures, comments, math spacing, fractions,
smash commands, large operator symbols, integrals, operator names,
! Undefined control sequence.
l.474 \buffer@\fontdimen13 \tenex

?

Comment: The free zipping tool from 7-zip.org should handle tar.gz files just fine

Comment: The compilation error is a completely different issue. I suggest you ask a new question about it. But you should definitely tell us which document you are trying to compile (*ideally* you would try to come up with an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), but a link to the arXiv document you're trying to run would certainly also help).

Comment: Seems that this is not a LaTeX document. Don't run it with `pdflatex`, run `pdftex`.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the .tar.gz file by clicking the link 'Download source' (under the heading 'Source').
2. Go to the location of the downloaded source, it will be named '0903.3428'. In the File Explorer, go to View, and make sure you have the "File name extensions" checkbox ticked. Rename the downloaded file to '09033428.tar.gz'.
3. Use your favourite archive program to extract 09033428.tar.gz - [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) will do the job.
4. Enjoy your tex source!

Comment: I HAVE A PROBLEM: the exe file is from **unverified** producer. I do not want to run unknown exe file on my PC. Do you please have a link to a verified one?

Comment: @user2925716 Verification costs money, something you often don't have when you give away your software for free. Then you'll probably have to find some commercial tool instead. No idea where.

Comment: @daleif Please, see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

(*I am actually following [@will-rushworth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182826/will-rushworth)'s [reply](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493819/149108). I just want to add one more line.*)

1. Download the .tar.gz file by clicking the link 'Download source' (under the heading 'Source').
   (Right side of arXiv page: Download:> Other formats> [Download Source])
2. Go to the location of the downloaded source, it will be named '1412.5930v3'. Rename that file to '1412.5930v3.tar.gz'.
3. Use [this website](https://extract.me/) to convert to .zip or to .tar file. For mac users, '1412.5930v3.tar.gz' file can be opened directly without any aid from any other website.

p.s. 1. Sharing a website does it always mean that the person who is sharing is affiliated with that website or trying to advertise?

2. 7-zip world in windows (at least at this moment). But max members of the scientific community don't use windows. That's why I thought to share an alternative way other than to use that software.

Comment: The added value of advertising a site does not seem significant enough to warrant a separate answer, especially since anyone with a computer probably already knows how to extract downloaded archives locally, or can easily find out. This also begs the question whether you are affiliated with this site and just saw an opportunity to disguise a spam post.